# What technologies could be made with the manipulation of quarks?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, nanotechnology

I’m trying to speculate on manipulating things on the level of quarks for a story. What could I do with that type of technology?

Answer (score 2):

Quarks refuse to connect up with each other except in very specific pairs and trios. Trios become neutrons and protons. Pairs become short-lived particles that are heavy (and can do damage to living beings and even constructs if they're exposed to lots of them, it's pretty close to neutron radiation in that regard).

The force that binds them together in pairs and trios is implicated in inertia/momentum and mass.

Most of the immediately interesting things you could do with them are almost certainly disallowed. Since they have 2/3 and -1/3 fractional charges, you might try to add those up such that you get something with the mass of a neutron, but a -1 charge (instead of the proton's +1). This sounds dumb, but such a particle would end up being like an electron that weighs 1900 times more than the typical electron, it might let you do catalyzed fusion (muon-catalyzed fusion's pretty fucking close to working... if muons last even a little bit longer before they decayed, we would have had fusion in the 1960s).

But without checking, I know that's a shit idea because I've never read it. I don't think you can just slap 3 down quarks together to get that (like, in the realm of the impossible, I've never read of it, rather than in the realm of "it decays in 0.04 picoseconds").

If quarks can be arranged in more than trios (theoretically suspect, not quite pseudoscience), then you could make ultra-dense matter with it. If you do this poorly, the ultra-dense matter consumes other matter near it and turns it into quark matter (bad... unless you aimed it at an enemy and live on another planet). But if you could stabilize it and prevent that (and shape it, a big if), you'd end up with some ultra-stiff nearly impenetrable armor. Like, this stuff's denser than neutronium.

The electrical charge of that matter could possibly be non-zero. It might be magnetic and weirdly so. Or super-conductive. Exotic properties (that don't violate the standard model) are not entirely improbable.

People experimenting with this are working with energy levels that are absurd. They'd have to be cautious in ways that aren't obvious to folks like us. Bad things could happen on the way to inventing and perfecting these technologies. And definitely bad things could happen to the people they don't like.

Having this technology doesn't necessarily unlock any hidden secrets of the universe... meaning they won't get Kardashev 4 energy levels from experimenting with this. But you'd probably need to be Kardashev 2 or higher... we currently can't smash apart hadrons into constituent quarks because the required energy levels are simply too high. To do so we'd need a supercollider that has a diameter something like the orbit of Neptune. And that's just to smash a few apart for science. To arrange them into neat little mechanisms as a matter of industry is levels beyond that. The point, which I've wandered away from is that the energy to make this stuff must come from somewhere else, because this technology doesn't give you higher energy levels (by itself). And it takes alot of energy to make. "Your quarkonium breastplate took 1300 solar masses worth of energy to make" isn't wildly off the mark.

Comment: You definitely _can_ arrange quarks in more than trios. Pentaquarks have been created. But they decay _very_ quickly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentaquark

Comment: Mike Scott, I was under the impression that whether or not Pentaquarks have been created is still controversial?

Comment: @CAEJones I was more under the impression that while they were real, no one was sure if they were their own particles, or a pair/trio that were close together so to speak. Don't their constituency always amount to what would be a viable triplet and meson if they were a bit apart?